# jquery if else doesnt give back an alert message

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

everything is writen in an external javascript file what I included in the html I also have the jquery link in there.

I tried to change put the if statment on diffrent positions in the code, I looked arround if the width was incorrect and some other things whitch are inrelevent at the moment.

When I changed the $foodcheck).width > '0px' to a < and the else if to a > the alert did work but ofc I only want it to pop up if the width = 0

I want it to give back the alert message.

```
var $foodcheck = $('#greenfood');
if(($foodcheck).width > '0px') {

    document.getElementById("f").onclick = function(){

        var random = Math.random();

        if(random > 0.0 && random <= 0.5) {

            $("#greenfood").animate({width: "-=30px"});

        } else if(random > 0.9) {

            $("#greenfood").animate({width: "-=80px"});

        } else {

            $("#greenfood").animate({width: "140px"});

        }
    };
 } else if(($foodcheck).width =< '0px'){
        alert("Works");
    }
```

Comment: `console.log(($foodcheck).width)` see it's value. `width` afaik is a function, not a property.

Comment: [jQuery's width()](https://api.jquery.com/width/) returns the computed width in pixels: `if(($foodcheck).width() > 0) {...`

Comment: It say's it is undifined, DO you have an I dea how I might fix this.

Comment: you have include the jquery in the page.

Comment: Are you using jQuery then? Because it's very definitely defined in jQuery.

Comment: I even added jquery it in the javascript file now still say undifined

Comment: Which version of jQuery then? I'm not aware of one that doesn't have it but still. `width` is a function on jQuery objects and it can raturn null if called, but "undefined" means you're not dealing with a jQuery object - is there a clash with another library? Something hijacking `$` so it calls something else?

Comment: Do you use Prototype? That wouldn't have a `width` function and it would hijack `$`.

Comment: In this small project i just linked the latest version. <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery's width()](https://api.jquery.com/width/) returns the computed width in pixels so you need to update you script to call it correctly. (note, its a function so needs the parenthesis).

Here's a working example:

```js
$(function(){
  
  var $foodcheck = $('#greenfood');
  if($foodcheck.width() > 0) {
    document.getElementById("f").onclick = function(){
        var random = Math.random();
        if(random > 0.0 && random <= 0.5) {
            $foodcheck.animate({width: "-=30px"});
        } else if(random > 0.9) {
            $foodcheck.animate({width: "-=80px"});
        } else {
            $foodcheck.animate({width: "140px"});
        }
    }
  } else {
     alert("$foodcheck is <= 0 or undefined");
  }
  
});
```

```css
#greenfood {background:green; width:200px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="greenfood">greenfood</div>
<button id="f">click</button>
```

**UPDATE:**
From your comments it's apparent that you want to check the width every time. Simply move the width checking clause inside the onclick event:

```js
$(function(){
  var $foodcheck = $('#greenfood');
  document.getElementById("f").onclick = function(){
        var random = Math.random();
    if($foodcheck.width() > 0) {
        if(random > 0.0 && random <= 0.5) {
            $foodcheck.animate({width: "-=30px"});
        } else if(random > 0.9) {
            $foodcheck.animate({width: "-=80px"});
        } else {
            $foodcheck.animate({width: "140px"});
        }
     } else {
        alert("$foodcheck is <= 0");
     }
  }
});
```

```css
#greenfood {background:green; width:200px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="greenfood">greenfood</div>
<button id="f">click</button>
```

Comment: Why would it? `$foodcheck` is *never* 0 or undefined... The fact that you're asking suggests to me that you meant for the script to check the width of `$foodcheck` every time `f` is clicked rather than just once before the `onclick` listener is applied?

Comment: Yes that is what I want shouldnt that happan

Comment: Not how you've coded it no. At present it checks the width then applies the onclick event listener *only* if the width is >0. The width is not measured again.

Comment: Oh I see, makes sence thanks, would you know what I should use to make it check everytime?

Answer (score 1):

You have quite a few problems with your code.

First of all, ">" and "<" should be done with numbers. Therefore the code `>"0px"` makes NO sense in this context, as you are really comparing the **dictionary order** of the characters in ASCII. Not the **value** of the integers.

i.e.

```
"a" < "b" //true as 'a' < 'b' => 97 > 98 (converted to ASCII numbers)
"ab" < "ac" // true as 'a' == 'a' and 'b' < 'c' 
"ab" < "ac" // true as 'a' == 'a' and 'b' < 'c'
"5px" > "11px" //true as '5' > '1'
```

What you should have done is compared the **value** like so:

```
5 > 11 //false as 5 < 11
```

Here is your corrected code:

```
var $foodcheck = $('#greenfood');
if($foodcheck.width() > 0) { // CHANGE: Additional Brackets were not needed. width should be width() 

    $("#f").click(function() { //This is the jquery way of doing events although your way also works
        var random = Math.random();

        if (random > 0.0 && random <= 0.5) {

            $foodcheck.animate({width: "-=30px"}); //IMPROVEMENT: used stored variable instead of finding the object again. 

        } else if(random > 0.9) {

            $foodcheck.animate({width: "-=80px"});

        } else {

            $foodcheck.animate({width: "140px"});

        }
    });
} else if ($foodcheck.width() =< 0){
        alert("Works");
}
```

Comment: The `random > 0.0` is rather superfluous as well - I'd leave it out, it adds nothing at all. The  `$("#greenfood")` in the cases is entirely not needed - the element is already looked up, the code should be using `$foodcheck.animate(/* stuff */);` instead. Otherwise, a good answer, I'd upvote it.

Comment: Sorry  I already left out alot of lines I wasnt sure if leaving out more would have bin good or bad

Comment: Mark the correct answer pls. Next time word the question so that it contains the minimum amount of code and but still has the problem. You can even figure out the answer yourself that way!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing it wrong at this line:

```
($foodcheck).width > '0px')
```

It should be

```
($foodcheck).width > 0)
```

And this line:

```
else if(($foodcheck).width =< '0px')
```

Should be:

```
else if(($foodcheck).width =< 0)
```

Comment: Should be `$foodcheck.width()`

Comment: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.' on if($foodcheck).width() > 0) {

Answer (score 0):

```
else if(($foodcheck).width =< '0px'){
```

this code throw error "<=" not "=<" if everything with the html is ok and you have element with id="f" this will fix it !

also `$foodcheck).width` must be `$foodcheck).width() <= 0` number not string like your example

Comment: Erm, it's also trying to compare a number to a string. You can't do that with these operators - it's a meaningless comparison.

Comment: @Vld: It's not actually meaningless and it can be done, but it isn't what he wants.

Comment: @squint It is meaningless in this case. I didn't think it was needed to specify.

Comment: @Vld: It's not meaningless. It has very specific meaning as defined by specification and will function correctly according to its design. And so you *can* do that with these operators.

Comment: @squint but does it or does it not help OP? The answer is "no" - it makes no sense for OP to use it, hence it's meaningless to use string comparison in that case.

Comment: Let's not have people walk away with the wrong idea about how JS works. Saying it may not give the desired result is far different from saying you can't do that with those operators because it's meaningless.